# Google Auth with Node.js using Typescript and Promise syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to implement google authentication using this tutorial: https://blog.prototypr.io/how-to-build-google-login-into-a-react-app-and-node-express-api-821d049ee670

but with Typescript and Promise syntax( these are the requirements) and I am getting this error:
[image]

This is the code:

```
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from 'src/adapters/http';
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';
import { config } from './../../../config';

const client = new OAuth2Client(config.auth.google.id);

export const makeLoginUser = () => {
  return (httpRequest: HttpRequest, httpResponse: HttpResponse) => {
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const { tokenId } = httpRequest.body;
    console.log(tokenId);
    try {
      const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: tokenId,
        audience: config.auth.google.id,
      });

      const { name, email, picture } = ticket.getPayload();

      resolve(httpResponse.status(200).send(email));
    } catch (error) {
      reject(httpResponse.status(429).send('Invalid request'));
    }
  });
};
```

};

Comment: What's your question? What _should_ happen if `ticket.getPayload()` returns `undefined`? Why _do_ you destructure `name` and `picture` out of the result even though you only need `email`?

Comment: What's your question? -> For know I just want to verify the IdToken.
What should happen if ticket.getPayload() returns undefined -> I will catch an error
Why do you destructure name and picture out of the result even though you only need email? -> I will use them after, but for testing purposes I want to check if I can get de email of the user for now

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? Do you understand the messages the compiler and ESLint are giving you? Have you researched their causes and possible solutions?

Comment: 'name' is an optional property of the tokenPayload type -> maybe use an intermediate step before assigning your return value to the variable 'name'
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/google-auth-library/5.8.0/interfaces/TokenPayload.html

Answer (score 4):

I had same error and solved it like this:

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';
import UserModel from './../models/user';
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

// @desc    Login with google
// @route   POST /api/user/google-login
// @access  Public

const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
export const signInWithGoogle = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { idToken } = req.body
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken,
    audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.getPayload() && response.getPayload()?.email_verified) {
      const email = response.getPayload()?.email
      const name = response.getPayload()?.name
      
      UserModel.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (user) {
          const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: "7d",
          })
          const { _id, email, name, role } = user
          return res.json({
            _id,
            name,
            email,
            role,
            token
          })
        } else {
          const password = `${email}${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`
          user = new UserModel({ name, email, password });
          user.save((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("ERROR GOOGLE LOGIN ON USER SAVE", err)
              return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Google Login Failed"
              })
            }
            const token = jwt.sign(
              { _id: data._id },
              process.env.JWT_SECRET,
              {
                expiresIn: "7d"
              }
            )
            const { _id, email, name, role } = data
            return res.json({
              _id,
              name,
              email,
              role,
              token
            })
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```